# 3D Line Graph manipulation

Tags: winforms, graph, 3d, cad, autocad-plugin

I am writing software for a device that would plot a **3D** graph/line plot of where someone has traveled. This plotting will be during post-processing of the data, so real time is not a requirement.

My key problem is, I can't find suitable tools or even other CAD software (eg. Autocad) which will plot a line graph (I imagine it would plot it as a 'path'?) from a data file (eg. CSV) **which I can then manipulate like a CAD model** (ie. move it around, rotate it to view from different angles, etc).

There is a real-time aspect to it where my computer will connect to the device at regular intervals, pull current location data, and store it. The computer will run and communicate through a Windows Forms app but only at the end do I need to plot the graph.

Would you have any suggestions on how to go about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: winforms is not the appropriate technology for this (nor for anything else I can think of). Looks like you need something like SharpDX or another 3D capable framework.

Comment: I don't need to do any plotting whatsoever IN winforms. I will use winforms to, for example, stick the data gathered into a .csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So much easier than I though it would be.

Basically, generate a new file named points.scr (this is an AutoCAD script file), that contains the following:

._LINE
0,0,0
1,2,4
2,2,4
C

Run this is AutoCAD by typing "scr" into the command prompt and selecting the points.scr file.

http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/AutoCAD-2004-2005-2006/script-to-draw-line/td-p/1219015